# is the following an example of serial voting?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I've had 6 downvotes on different question in the last 24 hours, I assume by the same user. Is that serial voting? I thought it was against the rules to keep downvoting questions from one user, in a short space of time.

Looks a little like someone wants to make it clear they don't like my questions, anyway, for whatever reason.

Comment: Also related: [What's the site policy for serial downvoters?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9706), [Is there an SE term for a sudden block down-voting of my questions like this?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10615)

Comment: For your specific instance, there were only 3 dv one day (-2 pts each). It looks like they were in quick succession so well may be a single person who saw one bad question then looked at two your others. But that doesn't necessarily imply the dvs were malicious. A longer sequence (I don't know how long but 3 is not it) is more indicative of malicious dv'ing. You did get some more downvotes last night and today, but since they are mostly on the same question it is separate people. Maybe you should think about the one question that is getting most of the dvs.